# Jquery İnput Keyup Thai,Eng and Space Chacter

Tags: javascript, regex, input, thai

I want to define the input key up in English, Thai and a space character. Other characters will be deleted.

```
$("#username").keyup(function () {


if (this.value.match(/d/g)){


this.value = this.value.replace(/d+/g,'');


}

else {

}

});
```

- Keyup: %'^%'& (delete)
- Keyup : Jack Boo (ok)
- Keyup : คน Boo (ok)
- Keyup : คน%^+ (delete)
- Keyup : คน452 (delete)

Help :))

Comment: Why would you want to limit input? Ok, reworded, why would you want to limit input as it is happening? What stops a person from pasting whatever they want to your field?

Comment: I want to limit the username to special characters and numbers. Space character, English character and Thai character will be released.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to validate after the fact? That is when the field changes event `onchange` then you can check for validity?

Comment: Are you talking about .change jquery function?

Comment: Whatever the name is, my point is what purpose is served by preventing the user from typing whatever they want? You can validate after

Comment: Use `.replace(/[^\sA-Za-z\u0E00-\u0E7F]+/g, '')`. See https://regex101.com/r/W4Dg3b/1

Comment: Thank youu.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `input` event, so you can also filter pasted text.

```js
$("#username").on("input", function(e) {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/[^a-z\u0E00-\u0E7F ]/gi, "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username">
```